# Why and when should you use typecasts?

Tags: oop, kotlin

Hey I just found out about typecasts, but I dont understand the concept behind it? Why would you use something like that. I tried to make an example to understand it better:

```
interface Fuel { 
    //Fuel.kt
    var usingFuel : Boolean
    var typeFuel : String

    fun printInfo(){
        println("Using this Fuel type: $typeFuel")
    }
}
```

```
class Airplane(name : String, age : Int, amountFuel: Double) : Vehicle(name, age, amountFuel), Fuel  {
    //Airplane.kt
    override var usingFuel: Boolean = true
    override var typeFuel: String = "Kerosin"

    override fun printInfo() { //Prints name, age etc of object
        super<Vehicle>.printInfo()
        super<Fuel>.printInfo()
    }
}
```

```
//Main.kt
var airplane : Airplane = Airplane(args)
var otherKerosin : Fuel = airplane
otherKerosin.fuelType = "Other Kerosin"
otherKerosin.printInfo()
airplane.printInfo()
```

And the output of `otherKerosin.printInfo()` is like the output of `airplane.printInfo()`, only that the fuel type is different. Now why should I do this, instead of creating a new airplane and changing the fuelType variable?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
var otherKerosin : Fuel = airplane
```

does not create a new instance of something. It's just getting a new reference to the same instance, but narrows its type to just the Fuel interface. Any change you make using `otherKerosin` also changes the original Airplane assigned to `airplane` (and vice versa) because both of these variables are pointing at the same instance.

In your given example, there would be no reason to do this. `otherKerosin` is needlessly restricting its type to `Fuel`, which hides the extra functions `Airplane` may have that aren't part of the `Fuel` interface. It provides you nothing that you can't do with the original `airplane` reference. But if you were returning your airplane from a function and the classes that call that function only need to work with a `Fuel`, you might want to simply return a `Fuel` so you aren't exposing more than you have to to the outside world. For example:

```
interface FuelProvider {
    fun provideFuel(): Fuel
}

class AirplaneProvider: FuelProvider {
    override fun provideFuel(): Fuel = Airplane() // Airplane is cast to Fuel
}
```

There's almost never a need to cast to a more narrow typed local variable. But sometimes you have a member property with a narrower type than the object you have at hand and you'll still want to assign it to that property. For example:

```
class FuelStorage(var fuel: Fuel? = null)

val storage = FuelStorage()
val airplane = Airplane()
storage.fuel = airplane // the Airplane is cast to Fuel to put it in the `fuel` property.
```

The `FuelStorage` class here doesn't care if its `Fuel` is an `Airplane` or some other type of `Fuel`.

I can think of maybe one example where you might want to do this, and that's if you have a long function you're writing and you want to limit your abilities with a variable to keep the available actions simpler. In a very long function, this could help you keep track of what you're doing. But, if a function is getting long enough for this to actually be helpful, it's probably a code smell.

Note, the type of casting you asked about and I discussed above is *implicit* casting, which is done automatically by assigning something to a property or variable for which the instance is a match, or by returning something from a function where the return type is a match.

You can also *explicitly* cast with `as` or `as?` which is done when the type you're casting to is not a known match for the type you're casting from. For example, if you have a `Fuel` and you want to cast it to an `Airplane`. A `Fuel` is not always an `Airplane` so you must explicitly cast to change the reference type. This will fail with an exception if the underlying instance is not in fact an `Airplane`, unless you use the safe cast `as?`.

And you can also *smart* cast by checking if a local variable is of a certain type or not null with an `if` check. After the check, the compiler can assume that the variable is referring to the checked type.

Comment: Good stuff — but, like the OP, you're talking about _implicit_ casts.  Could you add something about _explicit_ casts (`as <Type>`)?  You could mention smart casts, casting away nullability, &c.

Comment: I could, but I feel like that'd be regurgitating documentation without directly addressing the OP's specific confusion. Maybe I'll add a sentence to explain the different at least.

Comment: Thanks.  I felt it should be mentioned, at least — for posterity, if not for OP — but I couldn't be bothered to write a separate answer for it myself… :-)